# Add "ternary" column on SQL query

Tags: sql, t-sql

These are the my tables:

```
create table Utilizador(
    ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
    email varchar(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    name varchar(100),
    institution varchar(100),
);

create table Author(
    ID int,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY(ID) REFERENCES Utilizador(ID),
);

--Tables Evaluator and President are the same as Author
```

I want a view sort of like this:

```
CREATE VIEW GlobalViewOfUser AS
    SELECT U.ID, 
    U.email, 
    isAuthor = (EXISTS SELECT * FROM Author WHERE ID = U.ID) ? 1 : 0,
    isEvaluator = (EXISTS SELECT * FROM Evaluator WHERE ID = U.ID) ? 1 : 0,
    isPresident = (EXISTS SELECT * FROM President WHERE ID = U.ID) ? 1 : 0,
    (...)
    FROM User U, Author A, Evaluator E, President P 
    WHERE U.ID = A.ID AND U.ID = R.ID AND U.ID = P.ID
```

I don't know if something like this is possible...

Comment: What's wrong with a simple OUTER JOIN with for each of the tables and CASE statements? And for Pete's sake, stop using `SELECT *` when you only want to know if a row exists. Use `SELECT 1 FROM ...` instead. You don't need any of the columns from the table, and you definitely don't need every single one, when you only want to know if a row exists or not.

Comment: @Ken White, thanks! I'm new to this.., still lots of stuff I don't know about (I didn't know CASE could be used there :/ )
Also using `SELECT 1` instead of `SELECT *` is much better, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Start by adding the JOINs. You should end up with a single table in the FROM  followed by a JOIN for each of the other tables, like `FROM User u JOIN Author a ON a.ID = u.ID`.

Comment: @KenWhite The column list in an `exists` query is a syntactic placeholder. Using `*`, `NULL` or `1 / 0` will result in the same execution plan. (My personal preference is `42`.) If you can cite documentation showing otherwise I'm eager to learn.

Comment: This table structure seems strange in the first place. I've been working with databases for almost 20 years now and I can't think of more than 5 times I've needed to use a 1:1 relationship. Can one Utilizador have multiple roles (for instance, have the author and the Evaluator linked to the same Utilizador id)? Does the Author, Evaluator and President contain different columns (in addition to the ID column, of course)?

Comment: @Zohar Peled, Author, Evaluator and President are all Users. A User can be all, none, etc. . There's Articles written by 1 or multiple Authors and these can be reviewed by Evaluators that aren't Authors of that Article. Presidents are for another thing... we're already pretty deeply commited with the database to change anything (no time until submition) but if you have any ideas I'd love to learn :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want those isXXX columns to work, one thing which works on most SQL dialects is (for example the isAuthor):

```
SELECT 
...
U.email,
CASE WHEN A.ID = U.ID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS isAuthor
...
FROM User U, Author A ...
;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Damn, 
this is even better.    
guess I need some sleep

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```
CREATE VIEW GlobalViewOfUser AS
SELECT U.ID, 
    U.email, 
    isAuthor =  CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Author WHERE ID = U.ID) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END,
    isEvaluator = CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Evaluator WHERE ID = U.ID) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END,
    isPresident = CASE 
                    WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM President WHERE ID = U.ID) THEN 1
                    ELSE 0
                END
FROM User U FULL OUTER JOIN Author A ON U.ID = A.ID
 FULL OUTER JOIN Evaluator E ON U.ID = E.ID
 FULL OUTER JOIN President P ON U.ID = P.ID
GO
```

Don't know how I spent a couple hours on this.. >.>